# Write valualble the same string in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a command in perl

```
system("grep LISTEN /root/Desktop/m.txt | awk {'print $5'} | cut -f 1 -d ":"| sort | uniq > /tmp/entropy/dsip.txt");
```

The output error near `$5`.

How to write `$5` the same string, not a valuable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use non interpolating parentheses,

```
system(q{grep LISTEN ..});
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling `awk` and `cut` and `sort` from Perl? Really? Perl can do all the work itself:

```
open my $LISTEN, '<', '/root/Desktop/m.txt' or die $!;
my %uniq;
while (<$LISTEN>) {
    next unless /LISTEN/;
    my $fifth = (split)[4];
    $fifth =~ s/:.*//;
    undef $uniq{$fifth};
}
print $_, "\n" for sort keys %uniq;
```

Comment: +1. TIL `undef`. But missing `grep` functionality? may be `next unless /LISTEN/;` ?

Comment: `while (<>) { if (/LISTEN/) { ... } }`

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the `$`s:

```
print "\$literal\n";
```

to prevent Perl from interfering. Also escape the `$`s, to prevent shell from interfering:

```
system("echo \\\$1");
```

in which case shell will see `\$1` and echo will see `$1`.

Answer (score -2):

```
 awk {'print $5'}
```

should be

```
 awk '{print $5}'
```

---

ikegami says: The above is wrong since the two are equivalent

```
$ perl -E'say "<$_>" for @ARGV' awk {'print $5'}
<awk>
<{print $5}>

$ perl -E'say "<$_>" for @ARGV' awk '{print $5}'
<awk>
<{print $5}>
```

Comment: Those two are the same thing

Comment: @ikegami Now I'm confused. whether to down-vote original answer or up-vote your edit! :P