# Sed command inside perl script doesn't work

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed

I have a problem with a sed command located inside my perl script. When I execute the script I have following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
```

It concerns the line below:

```
$com1=`ls $path_correct | cut -f 1 -d "." | sed "s/.\{2\}$//" | sort > /tmp/usf-rpms`;
```

Why perl doesn't understand sed? What should be the correct syntax. I have tried deal with problem for few days but have no ideas to resolve the issue. Please help.

Comment: Place a \ before the $ in you substitution pattern and it should be fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write valualble the same string in perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070353/write-valualble-the-same-string-in-perl)

Comment: While it is possible to do things like this in Perl, I think it is quite horrible. First off, Perl has `glob` which acts like `ls`. It has `split` to cut fields. It has the substitution operator, just like `sed`, and it has `sort` as well, and the possibility to print to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a "-e" after the "sed" at least. And a "\" before the "$".

Comment: Yes, it's working now. That what I was looking for. You give me better understanding for using such parameters. Thanks!

Comment: Specifically, `$/` is a Perl variable, used to specify the input record separator, so you need to escape the dollar sign.